# CSV::Row and Hash navigation not working Ruby 2.3.3 Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, parsing, hash

I've parsed a csv using `CSV.parse` and am navigating it row by row. So the object we're looking at is a `CSV::Row` called `row`

This is a screenshot of what happens when I try to navigate `row`:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJozE.png)

As you can see I can call `.headers()` and as you'd expect `Strain` is in the list

When you look at the object itself you can see `"Strain":"818 Headband"`

So `row['Strain']` should equal `8181 Headband` except it returns `nil`

Naturally I tried `row.Strain`, `row["Strain"]`, `row[Strain]`,`row[:Strain]` none of which worked.

I also considered that it might be contained with in a one-entry array so i tried `row[0]['Strain']` and that also returned `nil`, unsurprisingly.

Assuming the issue was with the `CSV::Row` object, I called `row_hash = row.to_hash()` to get the object as a hash.

now that we're in basic ruby of course normal calls like `row_hash['Strain']` will work right?!? Nope. still `nil`.
[a view of row_hash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S8M3.png)

I'm so baffled, this isn't complex code at all. The docs for `Hash` and`CSV::Row` both list `[]` as a method and all the articles I've googled up list `row['key']` as the correct format...except it doesn't work for me.

Please help, I have a series of these csvs that I need to seed a database with and I can't do that if I can't navigate the hash!!

Edit 12:51pm 5/15/18:

```
csv.each do |row|
  row.each do |key, value|
    binding.pry
  end
end

$ key
=> "Strain"
$ value
=> "818 Headband"
$ row["Strain"]
=> nil
```

This can't be right...

Edit 1:05pm 5/15/18:

`$ = irb(main)`

```
$ csv_text = File.read('strain_data_formatted.csv')
=> ... (it dumped the whole csv to console)
$ csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true, :encoding => 'ISO-8859-1')
=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:118>
$ csv.first
=> #<CSV::Row "Strain":"818 Headband" "Subspecies":nil "Heritage":nil... 
$ csv.first["Strain"]
=> nil
$ csv.headers.first
=> "Strain"
$ csv.first[csv.headers.first]
=> "818 Headband"
$ csv.headers.first.class
=> String
$ "Strain".class
=> String
$ csv.headers.first == "Strain"
=> false
$ csv.headers.first
=> "Strain"
```

How is `csv.headers.first` a string with value "Strain" but it doesn't equal a string with value "Strain"?!?

Comment: What is the output of `row.has_key?("Strain")`. Also, have you tried iterating over the row with `each` and can you print out the key values for each element in the row? It does look like your code should work. Have you tried parsing the CSV in a regular IRB session without Rails? There may be something in your environment that's causing the oddity

Comment: Does `row[row.headers.first]` return the correct result? What does `row.headers.first.bytes` look like? (also please add code as text (use the code formatting button for it) instead of as images)

Comment: Leo - `row.has_key?("Strain")` returns `false` I'm surprised, we can see "Strain" as one of the options. I haven't tried iterating over the row with each, I'll try that now. I also haven't tried plain IRB so I can give that a go as well.



Lime - `row[row.headers.first]` returns `"818 Headband"` which is surprising because `row.headers.first` returns `"Strain"` but `row["Strain"]` still returns `nil`.

Comment: @IanBrooks what about `rows.headers.first.bytes` or `rows.headers.first.codepoints`? Those will tell you if there are any hidden/invisible characters in the header. If there are you'll need to `gsub` them out or delete the text in the original csv and retype it by hand to make sure nothing extra gets added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple Lime pointed me the right way! Thank you!

The issue is that there are hidden characters that don't get rendered when the header is printed as a string. Thats why `csv.first[csv.headers.first]` works but `csv.first["Strain"]` doesn't, even though `csv.headers.first` returns `"Strain"`. Presumably what its REALLY returning is something like `"invisiblestuffStrain"` (exaggerated but you get the idea).

To check and see if this is the case for you, call the `.bytes` method on the header and then call `.bytes` again on the string value you expect e.g.`"Strain".bytes`. If there is any difference, you have hidden characters.

Here is my actual console output:

```
$ csv.headers.first.bytes
=> [239, 187, 191, 83, 116, 114, 97, 105, 110]
$ "Strain".bytes
=> [83, 116, 114, 97, 105, 110]
```

You can see 3 extra characters being stored for that object that don't get shown when it's rendered as a string.

Simple Lime says: "you'll need to `gsub` them out or delete the text in the original csv and retype it by hand to make sure nothing extra gets added"

For me I had to modify the `.csv` directly from my text editor insted of using excel and saving it as a `.csv`.

Edit: I discovered that saving from an `.xlsx` workbook in MS Excel, to the `.csv` is what caused those strange characters to appear. I had to edit the file so I re-opend and re-saved and got that same error again when I re-seeded. Just as before, re-typing that first header from a text editor fixed the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the gsub method to remove the extra invisible characters

```
gsub("\xEF\xBB\xBF","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The file contains a [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

There are a number of ways you can remove it. See answers on [How can I remove the BOM from a UTF-8 file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/381230/how-can-i-remove-the-bom-from-a-utf-8-file)

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Exchange questions. Instead, include the essential portions of the answer here, and *tailor the answer to this specific question.*

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had your problem too until I realized that Ruby did not split the columns properly. I am putting my solution here just in case others are stuck in the same situation. All I needed to add was the `col_sep` property as follows:
`CSV.parse('file_name', headers: true, encoding: 'ISO-8859-1', col_sep: ';')`